# How to decode the OAuth2 access token to get the username by Resteasy

Tags: oauth-2.0, resteasy

I am a beginner to use the Resteasy to provide a OAuth2 service. Thanks very much!

When I use the grant_type of client_crdentials,

1st step: requesting the access token by a username and password.
2nd step: put the access token into authorization header to call API.

My question is, at the 2nd step, at the server side, how could I decode this access token to get the username that was used to request the access token in 1st step? Because, I want to know who is calling my API. Thanks very much!